# Getting "Inconsistent accessibility parameter type" error in blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor-webassembly, asp.net5

Hi just wanted to get some clarification

I am working on a project for Blazor web assembly and My Api controller is giving the following error message.

> Error CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IAuthRepository' is less accessible than method 'AuthController.AuthController(IAuthRepository)'    BattlesBlazor.Server

this is my service response class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BattlesBlazor.Shared
{
    public class ServiceResponse<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my IAuthRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BattlesBlazor.Server.Data
{
    interface IAuthRepository
    {
        Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(User user, string password);
        Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string email, string password);
        Task<bool> UserExists(string email);
    }
}
```

this is the AuthController

```
using BattlesBlazor.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BattlesBlazor.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
  
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthRepository _authRepo;

        public AuthController(IAuthRepository authRepo)
        {
            _authRepo = authRepo;
        }
    
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IAuthRepository> Register(UserRegister request)
        {
            var response = await _authRepo.Register(
                new User {
                    Username = request.Username,
                    Email = request.Email,
                    Bananas = request.Bananas,
                    DateOfBirth =request.DateOfBirth,
                    IsConfirmed = request.IsConfirmed

                }, request.Password );

            if (!response.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(response);
            }
            return Ok(response);
        }
    
    }
```

I have tried removing "public" from "public class AuthController : ControllerBase" which does take the error away however on PostMan there is no response

If someone could please provide me with some advice I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type in the code here is the issue:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IAuthRepository> Register(UserRegister request)
```

`AuthController` is `public`, and so is `Register`, so `IAuthRepository` must also be `public`.

From your definition, we can see that `IAuthRepository` is the default (`internal`):

```
interface IAuthRepository
{
    Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(User user, string password);
    Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string email, string password);
    Task<bool> UserExists(string email);
}
```

Generally, the solution is to make these agree. That is: you should make `IAuthRepository` public (i.e. `public interface IAuthRepository`). On the other hand, it seems strange that `Register` returns `IAuthRepository`. Should it not return `ServiceResponse<int>`?:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(UserRegister request)
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult' to 'BattlesBlazor.Server.Data.IAuthRepository'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) BattlesBlazor.Server  --- now this is the error i am getting

Comment: Looks like an exception, a pretty clear one at that.

Comment: @DumbPerson Yes, it seems unlikely that you want to return an `IAuthRepository`, as I noted above.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really should be paying more attention, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of your controller method to `Task<IActionResult>`:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRegister request)
...
```

Or make `IAuthRepository` public and always return the `response`.